# kdeconnect not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gnome, android, 14.04

kde-connect is available to install from software center in Ubuntu 14.04

[image]

but it's not showing up in the menu or search. I am using gnome shell

on running in terminal `gksu kdeconnect` I am getting these errors :

```
/home/parashar/.themes/zoncolorXtra-iOS/gtk-2.0/style/default.rc:29: Invalid symbolic color 'link_color'

/home/parashar/.themes/zoncolorXtra-iOS/gtk-2.0/style/default.rc:29: error: invalid identifier 'link_color', expected valid identifier

/home/parashar/.themes/zoncolorXtra-iOS/gtk-2.0/style/app/app-misc.rc:25: error: invalid string constant "treeview_header", expected valid string constant
```

`kde-connect` is the only app I know to bridge Ubuntu and Android... please help me to get it working or suggest an alternate app for Ubuntu 14.04 if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the kde-connect app I had to install kde-system-settings from Ubuntu software Center, and on my Android device I had to install the kde-connect app from google play.

[image]

[image]

[image]

1. install kde system settings on Ubuntu from Ubuntu Software Center
2. install kde connect on Ubuntu from Ubuntu Software Center
3. install kde connect on Android device from google play [kde connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.kdeconnect_tp)
4. pair the device and PC by opening kde-connect from kde system settings.